# MySQL Count Rows in Left-Joined Table

Tags: mysql, join, count, left-join

I'm trying to add a count of table t4 in the query below, without limiting the results. 
Something like:

```
 COUNT(t4.offer_to_purchase_id) AS count
```

but this limits the results to only those services appearing in t4, in spite of the left join

```
$sql = "SELECT s.*, q.categories, t4.*, payments.*, quotes.*
      FROM services s

      LEFT JOIN 
       (
      SELECT sc.service_id, GROUP_CONCAT(c.name) categories
        FROM services_categories sc JOIN categories c 
          ON sc.cat_id= c.cat_id
       GROUP BY sc.service_id
       ) q ON s.service_id = q.service_id

      LEFT JOIN offers_to_purchase t4
      ON s.service_id = t4.service_id 
      LEFT JOIN quotes ON quotes.service_id = s.service_id
      LEFT JOIN payments ON payments.service_id = s.service_id
      WHERE s.user_id = $user_id";
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should work (as it will count the non null values), but not sure how you would group the records to get it, seeing as you appear to be returning all the records from that table anyway.

If you want a count that can be used for all rows, while bringing back the rows from t4 anyway you could do something like this:-

```
$sql = "SELECT s.*, q.categories, t4.*, payments.*, quotes.*, t4_2.id_count
      FROM services s

      LEFT JOIN 
       (
      SELECT sc.service_id, GROUP_CONCAT(c.name) categories
        FROM services_categories sc JOIN categories c 
          ON sc.cat_id= c.cat_id
       GROUP BY sc.service_id
       ) q ON s.service_id = q.service_id

      LEFT JOIN offers_to_purchase t4
      ON s.service_id = t4.service_id 
      LEFT OUTER JOIN 
      (
        SELECT service_id, COUNT(offer_to_purchase_id) AS id_count FROM offers_to_purchase GROUP BY service_id
      ) t4_2
      ON s.service_id = t4_2.service_id
      LEFT JOIN quotes ON quotes.service_id = s.service_id
      LEFT JOIN payments ON payments.service_id = s.service_id
      WHERE s.user_id = $user_id";
```

Comment: +1 - I agree with @Kickstart the key point is that you need the second LEFT JOIN to the offers_to_purchase table with a SELECT that contains a GROUP BY in order to be able to retrieve the COUNT.  Wondering if this would work as well: `SELECT COUNT(*) AS id_count FROM offers_to_purchase WHERE offer_to_purchase_id IS NOT NULL GROUP BY service_id`

Comment: The left outer join seems to have worked thankyou, I just needed to add GROUP BY s.service_id at the end of the query. One user id can have several services, each with none, one or several offers to purchase - only the offers to purchase in t4 related to that service are returned, not all records

Comment: Thanks a lot, grouping rows in the left-joined table helped me. Some answerers here advice to group rows at the top level, which I think is not correct.